# Visual Studio Code Remote SSH Permission Denied (public key)

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote-ssh

I'm using Mac OS and can succesfully connect via terminal and ssh to the host with the command

```
ssh -i ~/full/path/to/private_key name@ip
```

But when I try to use the exact same command in Visual Studio Code using Remote-SSH "Connect to Host", it returns me "Could not establish connection to "ip": Permission denied (publickey)".

How to fix it? I've tried to add my local public key to the authorized_keys on host, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure you have read-only access to the private key.

Run the following to do so.

```
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/<path_to_your_key.pem>
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this..

After you click "Connect to Host", ONLY type in IP address (remove "`ssh -i ~/full/path/to/private_key name@`" from your example). It will then ask you to enter the passphrase for the ssh key. It should work if the passphrase is correct.

PS: Please also make sure you have the config information in the ssh configuration file ready. See details [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/10/03/remote-ssh-tips-and-tricks).

Comment: following the instructions from the link helped in my case.